# joins with Different Column Functions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a Table 1

```
Category  Year  Code  Amount Unit
 N        2014  1234   1000   8
 N        2014  3456   2000   2
 N        2014  8251   600    1037
 R        2014  8251   800    1037
```

And a Dimension Table DIM 1

```
Model_ID  Year  Code
   1       2014  1234
   2       2014   3456
   3       2015   1234
   4       2015    8251
```

Desired Result : Output Expected

```
 Category  Year  Code  Amount Unit
 N        2014  1234   1000   8
 N        2014  3456   2000   2
 N        2014  8251   600    1037
 R        2014  1234   0      8
 R        2014  3456   0      2
 R        2014  8251   800    1037
```

I want the Output as shown above . I have tried using left join.by doing left join i am getting 'null' for Amount and unit.i use nvl function for Amount 
i.e. **nvl(Amount,0)**

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE 1
LEFT JOIN Dim 1 TABLE 1 .year = dim 1 .year
AND TABLE 1.code = dim 1 .code
```

but the Values for Amount and unit acts Differently .
If there is no value For Amount then it should be '0'
and Unit Value should be same For 'N' and 'R' Division .Please Help me .thanks so much

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql` tag for Oracle question.

Comment: Your desired output does have any column from dim1 ? Are you sure you need a join here ... ?

Comment: if there is way to do it without join also .am happy .

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should use coalesce instead of NVL because NVL cast the second expression for string use the below link for further information.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Use the Following code

```
SELECT TABLE 1.Category, TABLE 1.Year,TABLE 1.Code, COALESCE(Amount,0),TABLE 1. Unit
FROM TABLE 1
LEFT JOIN Dim 1 TABLE 1 .year = dim 1 .year
AND TABLE 1.code = dim 1 .code
```

Comment: Thanks For the input i will do the Change  . How to achieve the Output as mentioned in the Question ? Please help me

Comment: Now check and please let me know if you find anything

Comment: I don't think nvl and Coalesce function is that problem here . i think there must be something done in Join and join Condition provided

Answer (score 0):

NVL() is fine. It looks you are missing JOIN condition ***'..AND TABLE_1.Category = Dim_1.Category'***

```
SELECT TABLE_1.Category, TABLE_1.Year,TABLE_1.Code, nvl((Amount,0),nvl(TABLE_1.Unit,0)
FROM TABLE_1
LEFT JOIN Dim_1 
ON TABLE_1.year = Dim_1.year
AND TABLE_1.code = Dim_1.code
AND TABLE_1.Category = Dim_1.Category;
```

Comment: Even if I do that . How will i get same Unit for Category 'N' and 'R' ?

Comment: You will get Category 'N' and 'R' from TABLE_1 regardless a match with DIM_1 due to OUTER JOIN. I think, You need to improve your question to express your expected output and how TABLE_1 and DIM_1 are joined.